# ogr2ogr from file to PostgreSQL 12 table fails

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr2ogr

Using CentOS 8.0 with PostgreSQL 12, PostGIS 3, and GDAL/OGR 3.0.1.
I want to append a file to a database table.

Previously (before upgrading to the new system) I used

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=dev user=admin password=123 host=0.0.0.0 port=5432" -lco "SCHEMA=myschema" -lco "GEOMETRY_NAME=geog" -append -sql "select ID as gid from input" input.gen
```

However, that fails now with

> ERROR 1: ERROR:  column s.consrc does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...nrelid = c.oid AND a.attnum = ANY (s.conkey) AND (s.consrc L...
>                                                                ^
>
> HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "s.conkey" or the column "s.c                                                                                onbin".
>
> ERROR 1: ERROR:  column s.consrc does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...nrelid = c.oid AND a.attnum = ANY (s.conkey) AND (s.consrc L...
>                                                                ^
>
> HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "s.conkey" or the column "s.c                                                                                onbin".
>
> ERROR 1: Layer myschema.input already exists, CreateLayer failed.
>   Use the layer creation option OVERWRITE=YES to replace it.
>
> ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
>   translation from sql statement.

If I make a PGDUMP with

```
ogr2ogr -f "PGDUMP" -lco "SCHEMA=myschema" -lco "GEOMETRY_NAME=geog" -append -sql "select ID as gid from input" test.dump input.gen
```

I can run that file in `psql` and import the data, but I would like to avoid that extra step of writing a large pgdump file.

**Notes**

- It also fails without `-append`
- It fails with other input data types
  and files as well (Shapefile, ArcGEN, and GeoJSON)
- Columns mentioned in the Error message are not part of my input data.
- I suspect that it has something to do with PostgreSQL 12 dropping OID

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same issue (this morning) and started to search for some solutions and the only thing I found is that is a GDAL PG12 problem, which was solved in  a [commit of GDAL in July 2019](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/963618e77de4eee5e7321f5f5ca7abc2b7287fa2).

This means we have to fix this manually or upgrade our GDAL. Your GDAL version is from June 2019, mine also.

Comment: Depends of OS, if app/python etc.

Comment: Do you know any PPA wich includes this fix in GDAL for Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Is there a way to get this bug fix in Debian 10 Buster?

Answer (score 3):

Can confirm that 3.0.1 has the bug, but it is solved in [3.0.2](http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/3.0.2/gdal-3.0.2.tar.gz) as mentioned correctly in the comments here by @michael. The version number is important to mention here.